# Getting Coordinates of Turtlebot

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-electric, gmapping, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have successfully created a map and our robot localizes well using AMCL. Now we want to be able to get the coordinates of the robot once it has localized itself within the map that we supplied. What is the best way to get the coordinates of the robot relative to the map?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31815/getting-coordinates-of-turtlebot/) by [zlalanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/2022/zlalanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2012-04-14

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to get the current location of the Turtlebot is using [TF](http://ros.org/wiki/tf). Assuming you are in C++ and already have a tf::TransformListener object as `listener`, that your robot's local frame is `base_link` and your map frame is `map`, you could use a block of code like the following:

```
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pBase, pMap;
pBase.header.frame_id = "base_link";
pBase.pose.position.x = 0.0;
pBase.pose.position.y = 0.0;
pBase.pose.orientation = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(0.0);
ros::Time current_transform = ros::Time::now();
listener.getLatestCommonTime(pBase.header.frame_id, "map", current_transform, NULL);
pBase.header.stamp = current_transform;
listener.transformPose("map", pBase, pMap);
// pMap now contains the pose of the robot transformed into map 
// coordinates according to the TF data available at time "current_transform"
```

If you are unfamiliar with the TF library, you should read through the tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-04-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zlalanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/2022/zlalanne/) on 2012-04-15**:
So this launches a node that publishes the data I need correct? Do I need to subscribe to a topic it publishes? Thanks for the help.